# Why my bash if statement keeps on returning true?

Tags: bash

My if statement for bash keeps on returning true and I don't know what is wrong with it. The below is my script. Despite running the modprobe command and it returning "install /bin/true" in my terminal, it always returns true which echoes "Not Compliant" instead of "Compliant" when I run my script which should have been the expected outcome.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$(modprobe -n -v cramfs 2> /dev/null | tail -1)" != "install /bin/true" ]];
then
        echo "Not Compliant";
else
        echo "Compliant";
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the modprobe command contains a trailing space.

Try:

```
if ! [[ "$(modprobe -n -v cramfs 2> /dev/null | tail -1)" =~ 'install /bin/true' ]];
```

or:

```
if ! modprobe -n -v cramfs 2> /dev/null | tail -1 | grep -q 'install /bin/true'
```

or (I think this is all you are trying to accomplish):

```
if ! modprobe -q cramfs; then ...
```